# What is the right way to initialize double pointer in c

Tags: c, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

As title, I want to know how to initialize double pointer with `sizeof` a pointer.

For instance

```
int **p=malloc(sizeof *p * rows);

for(size_t i = 0; i < rows; i++){
    p[i]=malloc(sizeof ? * cols);
}
```

What should I fill in `?`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `sizeof **p` would work, as would `sizeof *p[0]` or `sizeof *p[i]` or `sizeof p[i][0]`.  All of those are the same, so choose whichever is clearest (in menaing) to you

Comment: Generally, you should never write code like this unless you have specialized requirements. To allocate a 2D array, simply do `int (*arr)[cols] = malloc( sizeof(int[rows][cols]) );`. No loops. Unless you actually need each now to have individual sizes or similar specialized requirements.

Comment: See [Correctly allocating multi-dimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays) for details.

Comment: To allocate for a pointer to a "2D" array, code can use the simple `int (*p)[row][cols] = malloc(sizeof *p);`, but then access looks like `(*p)[r][c]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What should I fill in ?.

In general when you have

```
X = malloc(sizeof ? * NUMBER);
```

the `?` is to be replaced with the type that `X` points to. That can simply written as `*X`.

So the line:

```
p[i]=malloc(sizeof ? * cols);
```

is to be:

```
p[i]=malloc(sizeof *p[i] * cols);
```

Notice that a 2D array can be created much simpler. All you need is

```
int (*p)[cols] = malloc(sizeof *p * rows);
```

Here `p` is a pointer to an array of `cols` `int`. Consequently `sizeof *p` will be the size of an array of `cols` `int`.

Using this VLA based technic means that you can allocate the 2D array using a single `malloc`. Besides making the code more simple (i.e. only 1 `malloc`) it also ensures that the whole 2D array is in consecutive memory which may give you better cache performance.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, if the col length is the same for all elements one should create a pointer a VLA array instead to only get 1 call to malloc.

Comment: Note that `int (*p)[cols]` is no longer an OP "double pointer", yet is still a good idea to consider.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want `p` to be an array that can hold pointers, and the number of pointers is `rows`.  So you can allocate memory for `p` like this:

```c
int ** p = malloc(sizeof(int *) * rows);
```

Now if you want `p[i]` to point to an array that holds `cols` ints, do this:

```c
p[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * cols);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that's really helpful. But I want to initialize with `sizeof` a pointer (just curious).

Comment: What do you mean?  Your secondary allocations are for arrays of *ints*, not pointers, so it's best to use `sizeof(int)` or use `sizeof(x)` where `x` is some variable of type `int`.

Comment: I get it. Thanks a lot.